# Sublime Text 2 in OSX: all fonts are bold regardless of theme or font

Tags: font

I have a weird problem on mac (OSX 10.7): any theme or font I choose - all fonts appear in bold. I sync all settings with Dropbox and on Windows 7 and Ubuntu the fonts are normal.

Don't know if it's an OSX problem or sublime, but did anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck "Use LCD font smoothing when available" in System Preferences > General then restart Sublime Text.

Answer (score 3):

on retina screen, i was used `"font_options": ["gray_antialias"]` and got perfect result

Answer (score 2):

I haven't expereinced this issue but it looks like in your sublime preferences you can define font options in which you can say `no_bold`

```
{
    // Valid options are "no_bold", "no_italic", "no_antialias", "gray_antialias",
    // "subpixel_antialias" and "no_round" (OS X only)
    "font_options": ["no_bold"]
}
```

From [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070984/how-to-enable-bold-fonts-in-sublime-text2-in-linux)

Comment: I already use `no bold`